# Really basic example of Lagrangian duality

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, duality-theorems

I have this really basic optimization problem and I need to find the solution with the Lagrangian duality (even though **I know that it is an overkill**).

$$
\min_x \quad  2x+2 \\
s.t \quad x\geq 0
$$

It is easy to show that the minimum is $2$ in $x=0$, but if I want to solve the Lagrangian dual problem, I found the following:
$$
\max_\lambda \min_x \quad 2x+2+\lambda(-x) \\
s.t \quad \lambda\geq 0
$$

And, finally, I got stuck at this point, when I have to solve this:
$$
\min_x \quad 2x+2-\lambda x
$$
this function is not bounded, and the minimum (I think) is $-\infty$. Where is my error? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your optimization problem,
$$
\max_\lambda \min_x \ 2x+2+\lambda(-x) \\
s.t \quad \lambda\geq0
$$

Can be seen as,
$$
\max_\lambda f(\lambda) \\
s.t \quad \lambda\geq0
$$

Now this $f(\lambda)$,
$$ 
   f(\lambda) = \min_x \ 2x+2-\lambda x = \begin{cases} 
      -\inf & \lambda < 2 \\
      2 & \lambda = 2 \\
      -\inf & \lambda > 2
   \end{cases}
$$
Hence optimal value of your function $\max_\lambda f(\lambda)=2$ and $\lambda =2$ is your solution.

Comment: Thank you very much!